# simple mysql query taking 16+ seconds

Tags: mysql

Simple sql query taking 16 seconds plus. Here is the table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `udr` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `upbytes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `downbytes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `traffictype` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `traffictype` (`traffictype`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

There are 16 million records. (Originally there were 141 million, I pruned to see if it was the problem)

Query in question is (like)

```
select time,upbytes,downbytes
 from udr
  where userid = 315533 and 
        time between '2014-01-01 14:35:28' and '2014-01-02 14:35:28'
```

I thought the problem was the time part so I removed the time condition and tried following

```
select time,upbytes,downbytes from udr where userid = 315533
...
10282 rows in set (19.42 sec)
```

Still the query is taking 16 seconds plus.

Here is my key config params

```
key_buffer    = 32M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack    = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
```

ran out of ideas on this one.

Thanks

```
mysql> explain select * from udr where userid = '315533';
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | udr   | ref  | userid        | userid | 4       | const | 12738 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

iotop reports heavy disk io. I suspect mysql is retrieving all records to memory.

Comment: You have a `time` column but query to a `datetime`?

Comment: use `explain select` and see the output. maybe some indexes are not created or not working

Comment: How many records does user `315533` return?

Comment: Will it be better if you change the engine to MyISAM?

Comment: Do `EXPLAIN <your_query>`, as it was already suggested, and post the results in your question in textual form

Comment: I tried iotop and observed that there is a heavy disk read

Comment: Try adding an index on both the columns you're matching against, like ALTER TABLE udr ADD KEY ( `userid` , `time` ); or ALTER TABLE udr ADD KEY ( `time`, `userid` );. Test both to find out which is faster. (Problems with SQL and SO-syntax, you'll sort it out :) )

Comment: There are 10282 queries for user 315533. disk io was 16.7 M/s

Comment: mysql> explain select * from udr force index (userid) where userid = '315533';
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | udr   | ref  | userid        | userid | 4       | const | 12738 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

Comment: table structure is unusual because backward compatibility is maintained. This table is 9 years old. :)

Comment: please put that in your post, not in the comments. I don't see any indexes being created; without them, mysql can't treat the data as sorted and is basically running through all 16 million records blind.

Comment: Which key is PRIMARY!?!?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT time,upbytes,downbytes
    FROM udr
    WHERE userid = 315533 AND
    time BETWEEN '2014-01-01 14:35:28' AND '2014-01-02 14:35:28'
```

In this query, you are searching on two columns, `time` and `userid`. You do have indexes on both these columns, but MySQL can only use one of them at a time.

MySQL will choose to use either the `time`-index or the `userid` index. If it chooses `userid`, 12738 rows will have to be retrieved, which causes the long query time. MySQL will then search through the retrieved data to filter out the `time`-column.

The solution is to add a index on both the columns:

```
ALTER TABLE udr ADD KEY (`userid`, `time`);
```

This way MySQL can search on both `userid` and `time` without retrieving data first.

NOTE: It can take a few minutes to create the new index, be patient.

Comment: nice one. But the query only with userid was still taking almost same amount of time.

Comment: Yes, because it still has to get over 250MB. If you limit the results with another column, like `time`, the number of rows returned will be far less, and the query will run faster. If you want all the rows for a single `userid`, the query cannot be made any faster.

Comment: How do you get 12738 rows = 250MB? That would mean each row is 20KB.

Comment: @MartinSmith Bacause I forgot to divide by 1024 two times, removed that.

Comment: ALTER TABLE  `cablenet`.`udr` ADD INDEX (  `userid` ,  `time` ) is done. But the improvement is not significant. But when I changed table to MyISAM and voila! Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about MySQL storage but 4 integers and a datetime must be, what, an absolute max of 50 bytes (rounding up generously and adding something on for luck). So 16 seconds to go through less than 1MB of data seems unbelievably slow to me.

Comment: I doubt its because of the index, because if you have an index on either column then the search is O(log N) (B-Tree) and the DB has to fetch only logN rows.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I have a huge InnoDB-table myself whith queries on multiple columns, runs very fast with correct indexes. Why did the perfomance in this case improve so much when he changed engine? Maybe the table was very old and messy on the disk?

Comment: I don't know, it might be a bug or ... everything. But assuming he has an index on userid and userid is unique, the  WHERE userid = 315533 statement must return 0 or 1 rows and then the db should check the time column. This one row should be returned in time proportional to logN, because of the B-Tree index. Maybe for some reason the db is not using the index ? Try "explain select", it might give you a hint what's wrong

Comment: @Atle I suspected something was wrong with the innodb file on the disk. changing the engine should never have resulted the performance improvement by this much, everything else being the same. I took a spare server and dumped data on new machine, still took 13 seconds for the query. The problem is still mysterious.

Comment: @atle  If you could post your SHOW INDEX FROM table_name and one sample query, I suspect we will see that you do indeed have a PRIMARY key, rather than no PK.  Generally PK use is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make indexing in `time` and `userid`.you can easily built index using phpmyadmin or sqlyog.

Comment: query only with userid was taking almost same time.

Comment: Yes because of between and time condition it take time.Make indexs in your table and it will obviously reduced time.

Answer (score 0):

> But the query only with userid was still taking almost same amount of
>   time.

You can't do much more.
What are your hardware specs?
My configs are average and higher than yours:

```
query_cache_size =  64 MiB
key_buffer =  128 MiB
max_allowed_packet  =  16M
thread_stack    =  294 Kb
thread_cache_size       = 128
query_cache_limit =  128 KiB
```

I suggest to use MariaDB / Percona instead of standard MySQL and try again with MYISAM. They improved very much with Aria...